# Can't show FloatingActionButton in app screen

Tags: android, vector, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat, floating-action-button

I updated the Android Support Library in Android Studio to version 23.2 to get started with the Bottom Sheets, but after that, I couldn't show the FloatingActionButton in app screen. I'm getting the following error:  **"android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f020054"**

I saw the article that talk about the flag to enable support vectors in gradle, as mentioned in the official blog and Chris' post: https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88 .
﻿**I'm using the version 2.0.0-beta6 of the Gradle plugin.**

As you can see below I already enabled support vectors in my gradle file.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "br.com.jobcare.myapp"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
        }

     }

     dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    }
```

And below follows the layout:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:context=".presenters.activities.MainActivity">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container_body"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
                android:name="br.com.jobcare.myapp.presenters.fragments.FragmentDrawer"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/add_event_floating_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
                android:onClick="showAddChoicePopupMenu"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's bug in Android Studio, see here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201861

Comment: Thank you @Arcao
You are right. The code it's working for me now on device. But in Android Studio the error still appears in screen.